# Are there any c# Protocol buffers tcp messaging libs out there?

Tags: protocols, protobuf-net, buffer

Basically i want to pub/sub Protocol buffer messages over a tcp async socket.

Are there any open-source libs that pub/sub Protocol buffer messages over tcp?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a push - how about a redis node? Ultimately though any pub/sub implementation would suffice as long as it handles binary. I happen to like redis as it solves a host of problems in one tool; [BookSleeve](http://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/) is a fully async binary-safe redis client that works well with BLOBs such as protobuf fragments.

Disclosure: since I wrote both protobuf-net and BookSleeve I might be biased...

Comment: But can I run Redis on windows?